# DOM manipulation with jquery and Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, uikit, dom-manipulation

I'm using `AngularJS` into my web application. I Also use angular routing into my app. So, I add the templates into `<ui-view>` and there is nothing in the DOM at first.

Also I use `uikit` and it's ui components. All of it's components works fine with my routing. But my own `js` file (ex. for toggling menu), doesn't work, because of angular routing.

**First:** Why does uikit work fine, but my `js` file doesn't?

**Second:** What is the solution? Any idea?

**Update:**

Both of uikit.js and my own js is into `<head>`.

Here is a sample code my js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// some more code ...
  if( $("body").hasClass("rightpanel_small") ){
        $(".rightpanel_menu").removeClass("active");
  }
})
```

Comment: Add the relevant code to your question please - it's really frustrating when people ask for help without giving us anything that would help us help you... It's like asking "I have a function that calculates two numbers together, but it's not working. Any idea why?" without posting the code in question. There's no way anyone can know what's wrong without seeing the code.

Comment: @Fissio Sorry, please see update part. Thanks. But my problem wasn't about a small piece of code.

Comment: don't mix jquery code with angularjs code. If you have something you cannot achieve through angular and you still need to use jquery, consider $scope.$apply() function to let know angular which changes have been made with jquery - angular's context is not aware of jquery changes unless you tell it that something has changed and force another digest cycle